# Why opening websocket continuously use network?

Tags: websocket

I wan to make a chat app with AutobahnAndroid. My problem is that after opening a websocket connection, wifi icon in top left corner of mobile is in transferring data. Is there a way to solve this problem? For example when a new message received it show transfer icon and when there is no message it does not use network like Telegram?

Comment: So, why do you want to use Websocket? Use plain http.

Comment: I want to subscribe people in chat room of new message. It isn't possible with plain http.

Comment: I don't use AutobahnAndroid, by the way the WebSocket protocols usually have to implement the "keep alive" signal. That's probably the reason why you are detecting network traffic.

Comment: So how can I solve this issue. Are there any solution instead of websocket for android?

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket connections are persistent. They do not actually use networking resources when there are no messages being sent, but there is still an open socket. Maybe this triggers the transmission icon. And as [pietro909](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252025/pietro909) stated in one of the comments, to prevent the system or intermediaries from closing the connection, you may be sending keep alive pings. 
In the end, you can't have both: A push channel from the server and network activity only when there are messages.

Comment: So why chat apps like Telegram did it. They use push channel and use network when there are new messages.